# How do I import a model which has .mat and texture files in separate folders?

Tags: import, .fbx, collada

I have a model that came in three separate folders

folder #1 has three .mat files

folder #2 has the model in .psk, .fbx, .dae and .smd formats

folder #3 has textures in .tga format

how do I import this model into blender with textures and posable?

Comment: try putting your model files in the same folder as the .mat file

Answer (score 0):

.mat are only for 3ds Max only, it reads it to auto apply textures from the importer, in Blender you will need to setup textures manually.